# Picasso doesn't load image from File

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I'm loading an image from the apps data folder into an ImageView using Kotlin on Android. To load the image Picasso is used but the loading process does not work.

Path is:

> file:///data/user/0/at.guger.speiseplan/files/KW9.jpg

I tried:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(file.absolutePath).fit().into(imvMenu)
Picasso.with(this).load("file://" + file.absolutePath).fit().into(imvMenu)
```

and `file` is generated with the following method:

```
private val sMenuFileName: String = "KW%d.jpg"
fun getMenuFile(): File {
    return mContext.getFileStreamPath(String.format(sMenuFileName, Utils.getWeekOfYear()))
}
```

The file does exist, because loading into a WebView works:

```
String sHTML = "<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"><style type=\"text/css\">body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}</style></head><body><img src=\"" + "file://" + file.toString() + "\" width=\"100%\"></body></html>";

mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://schuelerwohnheim-steyr.com", sHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

And loading the image using BitmapFactory does also work, so why does Picasso not load the image?

```
imvMenu.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve made this mistake many times myself

Change

```
Picasso.with(this).load(file.absolutePath).fit().into(imvMenu)
Picasso.with(this).load("file://" + file.absolutePath).fit().into(imvMenu)
```

To

```
Picasso.with(this).load("file://" + “${file.absolutePath}”).fit().into(imvMenu)
```

If it is just a Val or var like

```
absolutePath
```

Then it would work but since you have that fancy “.” In there it requires “${}”